# CSS Issue with (ODD) selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to create a loop where I apply different styling to each odd element.
For this reason, using :nth-child(odd) would be great.
However, for some reason that I don't understand, :nth-child(odd) gets applied to each element, not just the odd ones.

I created a codepen to showcase the issue.

```css
h3.post-title a:nth-child(odd) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">

  <div class="ts-post-thumb">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="#" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
    <a class="post-cat ts-blue-bg" href="#"> </a>
    <h3 class="post-title">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </h3>
    <span class="post-date-info">
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
    
        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">

  <div class="ts-post-thumb">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="#" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
    <a class="post-cat ts-blue-bg" href="#"> </a>
    <h3 class="post-title">
      <a href="#">Title</a>
    </h3>
    <span class="post-date-info">
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
          
        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">

  <div class="ts-post-thumb">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="#" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
    <a class="post-cat ts-blue-bg" href="#"> </a>
    <h3 class="post-title">
      <a href="#">Title</a>
    </h3>
    <span class="post-date-info">
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
          
        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">

  <div class="ts-post-thumb">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="#" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
    <a class="post-cat ts-blue-bg" href="#"> </a>
    <h3 class="post-title">
      <a href="#">Title</a>
    </h3>
    <span class="post-date-info">
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Pbalazs89/pen/eYjZNya

I tried selecting the elements directly (h3.post-title a:nth-child(odd) {}) and I tried selecting their parent container as well (.ts-grid-item-2 h3.post-title a:nth-child(odd) {}) The parent container is not present in the container, I just wanted to list what I tried.

Comment: Because in your h3 you have only 1 a tag, and you targeting it with nth-child(odd), infact 1 is odd....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your actual selector you target every `a` inside you `h3 title`.
You have to target every `a` in the odd element container.

```
div.item:nth-child(odd) h3.post-title a {}
```

With this selector you target an `a` element inside an `h3` with class `.post-title` inside any odd div with class `.item`

```css
div.item:nth-child(odd) h3.post-title a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">

  <div class="ts-post-thumb">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="#" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
    <a class="post-cat ts-blue-bg" href="#"> </a>
    <h3 class="post-title">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </h3>
    <span class="post-date-info">
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
    
        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">

  <div class="ts-post-thumb">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="#" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
    <a class="post-cat ts-blue-bg" href="#"> </a>
    <h3 class="post-title">
      <a href="#">Title</a>
    </h3>
    <span class="post-date-info">
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
          
        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">

  <div class="ts-post-thumb">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="#" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
    <a class="post-cat ts-blue-bg" href="#"> </a>
    <h3 class="post-title">
      <a href="#">Title</a>
    </h3>
    <span class="post-date-info">
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
          
        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">

  <div class="ts-post-thumb">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="#" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
    <a class="post-cat ts-blue-bg" href="#"> </a>
    <h3 class="post-title">
      <a href="#">Title</a>
    </h3>
    <span class="post-date-info">
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```